# Complicated (?) nesting

Tags: xquery

I'm new to this and it's easy to get stuck in SQL mode.
I've prepared a small example to illustrate my problem.

```
    <bigXML>
    <Product>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute>
                <Descriptions>
                    <Description languageCode='DE'>Farbe</Description>
                    <Description languageCode='EN'>Color</Description>
                </Descriptions>
                <Value>0000ff</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Descriptions>
                    <Description languageCode='DE'>Länge</Description>
                    <Description languageCode='EN'>Length</Description>
                </Descriptions>
                <Value>2 mm</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Descriptions>
                    <Description languageCode='DE'>Name</Description>
                    <Description languageCode='EN'>Name</Description>
                </Descriptions>
                <Value>Circle</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Product>
</bigXML>
```

I want to get to the VALUE of **0000ff**.
Here's my attempt:

```
<Reply>{for $i in //Product where $i/Attributes/Attribute/Descriptions/Description="Color" return $i/Attributes/Attribute/Value}</Reply>
```

It returns the values of all VALUE tags eventhough I specifically (maybe?) asked for the one where Description is Color.

Please tell me what part of the WHERE syntax I'm getting wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only fix the `Product` node in the `for` loop and then traverse down to the `Attribute`s twice (once to check, and once to retrieve the `Value`), you cannot make sure that you only get values of `Color` attributes. Your query says: "For every `Product` *that has one or more `Color` attributes*, return all attribute values."

One easy fix is to just iterate over attributes instead of products:

```
<Reply>{
  for $attr in //Product/Attributes/Attribute
  where $attr/Descriptions/Description="Color"
  return $attr/Value
}</Reply>
```

If you also need the product reference, you can use nested loops:

```
<Reply>{
  for $i in //Product
  for $attr in $i/Attributes/Attribute
  where $attr/Descriptions/Description="Color"
  return $attr/Value
}</Reply>
```

You can also replace the `where` with an *XPath* predicate and make the whole expression shorter:

```
<Reply>{
  //Product/Attributes/Attribute[Descriptions/Description="Color"]/Value
}</Reply>
```

Comment: There's a great tendency for people with a SQL background to try and write every query as a FLWOR expression. The vast majority of queries can be expressed as simple path expressions. No variables needed, and no "where" clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Attribute[Descriptions[Description='Color']]/Value
```

It selects `0000ff`.